# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-home

I am trying to install some software (Shibboleth) in Ubuntu 14.04. I already have Java 7 OpenJDK installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/`, and I have these lines in `/usr/environment`

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
export JAVA_HOME
```

If I type `echo $JAVA_HOME` I correctly get `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`.
However, when I try to install Shibboleth I always get `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. Cannot execute java`.

Interestingly, if I type `java` command it works (it refers to /usr/lib/java which is a link to the right one). However, when I try to run `bash bin/install.sh` of Shibboleth, I get the JAVA_HOME error

I already tried setting `JAVA_HOME` to the `jre` folder with same result. Any ideas?

Comment: First install necessary packages `apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless`
`apt-get install tomcat7`  and see.

Comment: I already have both of them installed

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add both `JAVA_HOME` & `PATH` to your `~/.profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And, add following to your `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
export JRE_HOME
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

For more info, Refer [Documentation](https://shib.kuleuven.be/docs/idp/2.x/install-idp-2.1-rhel.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this but same error. Interestingly, if I type "java" command it works. However, when I try to run "bash bin/install.sh" of Shibboleth, I get the JAVA_HOME error.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps now

Comment: Still same error. Is it OK that all these variables are defined without quotes? I didn't even had a .bash_profile or /etc/profile.d/java.sh files

Comment: Ubuntu use `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`, updated my answer

Comment: `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` you need to create one, use cat.

Comment: For some apps such as PDFsam: `~/.bashrc` with jdk version 11.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I did

```
EXPORT JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64'
```

Works.

Comment: In my case using single quotes worked!

Answer (score 6):

from Ubantu terminal execute:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

to test maven run:

```
mvn --version
```

it will give output:

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.x.xxx, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-47-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Your editor.

```
sudo vim /etc/profile
```

add these 2 lines at the end of the file

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"  
export PATH=JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then

```
source /etc/profile
```

Check

```
mvn -version
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the path to bin folder where java, javac files are found.
In your case it might be /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin

Comment: Already tried, same result. Please, note that I can run the command "java" properly. The error is displayed when I try to run bin/install.sh on Shibboleth.

Answer (score 0):

I issue is that the install.sh script which you are running has the java path wrong.

Edit the file using nano

```
    sudo nano idp-install.sh
```

or vim editor

```
    vim idp-install.sh
```

and change the line which corresponds to java path and add the correct java path. This will solve your problem.

P.S. This solution is specific to the java path for Shibboleth installation.

Answer (score 0):

For future comers, please note this problem usually happens because `Java` is not properly set in your environment. Take the following steps to fix the problem

first, check where your `JDK` is using the following command
`cd /usr/lib/jvm/{jdk-version}`
Now that you have the full path where your `JDK` is, copy the whole path like so, in my case I have `jdk1.8.0_261`

So you copy `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261` path, open `/etc/environment` and set the JDK path properly as follows

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261:/opt/apache-maven-3.6>
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261
M2_HOME="/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3"
```

Note that I have added the `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261` to the `PATH` variable and also to the `JAVA_HOME` variable,

This should resolve the error `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. Cannot execute java` since the `JDK` is now properly set in the `PATH` and in the `JAVA_HOME`, then for the Shibboleth you can also now define the path where it is installed like so (This is an example-  don't know how to set Shibboleth)

```
SHIBBOLETH_HOME="/opt/shibboleth-{version}"
```

Answer (score 0):

export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64'

Answer (score 0):

For ubantu :

To correct JAVA_HOME variable

step 1 : Open the /etc/environment file in a text editor with sudo privileges. You can use the following command:

```
    **command : sudo nano /etc/environment**
```

step 2 :  correct the variable

**JAVA_HOME="/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"**

step 3 : press **ctrl+o**

step 4 : click on **Enter**

step 5 : press **ctrl+x**

Done now try your work

all the best