# WSO2 Identity Server - Carbon cannot execute Java

Tags: java, wso2, ubuntu-16.04, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I installed Oracle JDK `jdk1.8.0_144` in `/usr/local/java` and set the symlinks as below.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws
```

After that, I followed the installation guide in the WSO2 documentation and set `JAVA_HOME` as below.

```
nano /.bashrc
```

added the variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I close the old terminals and open a new one and run:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

and I get

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
```

However, when I run `sh wso2server.sh` I get the error:

```
JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
CARBON cannot execute java
```

error.

Comment: Try enclosing JAVA_HOME path with quotes as below,
`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144"`

Answer (score 4):

You should try to add the following into your `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

There is similar issue: [Ubuntu: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966648/ubuntu-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly)

There are many other causes of this issue:

1) You are running the server as the super user (sudo) which is not required. However I think you dont have the `JAVA_HOME` set in super user environment.
2) You can try: `sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle ./wso2server.sh`
3) You should probably be setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre` rather than `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`.

4) Your version of Identity Server does not support java 8.

Comment: Identity Server do support java 8 since version 5.1.0. Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Installation+Prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

replace your java home path in wso2server.sh line no 52

```
#JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/${JAVA_VERSION}/Home
```

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home